# How to test "ApplyTo.Post" RuleSet in ServiceStack

Tags: testing, servicestack

I want to test my validator for post behavior described below.

```
public interface ITestValidator
{
    bool IsExists(string testName);
}

public class TestValidator : ITestValidator
{

    public bool IsExists(string testName)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class TestRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Level { get; set; }
}

public class TestRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<TestRequest>
{
    public ITestValidator Validator { get; set; }
    public TestRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.Level).Must(p => p.HasValue && p > 0);
        RuleSet(ApplyTo.Post, () =>
        {
            RuleFor(p => p.Name).Must(p => !Validator.IsExists(p));
        });
    }
}
```

I created a test with xunit as below.

```
[Fact]
public void test_should_not_be_valid()
{
    var validator = new TestRequestValidator();
    var validationResult = validator.Validate(new TestRequest
    {
        Level = 1,
        Name = null
    });

    Assert.False(validationResult.IsValid);
}
```

This test is successed for

```
RuleFor(p => p.Level).Must(p => p.HasValue && p > 0);
```

But it is not working for

```
RuleFor(p => p.Name).Must(p => !Validator.IsExists(p));
```

How can i test validators for multiple operations like  "ApplyTo.Post, ApplyTo.Get, ApplyTo.Delete"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to test the validators for a HTTP Method with something like:

```
var validator = new TestRequestValidator { 
    Validator = new TestValidator()
};

var result = validator.Validate(
    new ValidationContext(requestDto, null, new MultiRuleSetValidatorSelector("POST")));

Assert.False(result.IsValid);
```

Comment: How i can use this with "service.Any(new TestRequest{})"?

Comment: @MustafaGülmez Validators are executed inside Request Filters which are [executed before the Services are created](http://docs.servicestack.net/order-of-operations), you'd need to [create a Self Host Integration Test](http://docs.servicestack.net/testing) in order to execute the full request pipeline.